# Trying to pull data between Excel spreadsheet tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two spreadsheets right now and I'm trying to figure out a way to easily pull data from sheet 1 that matches corresponding data in sheet 2.

Sheet 1:

```
companyname  companyid
```

Sheet 2:

```
companyname companyphone
```

I was just wondering if there is an easy way to copy the phone number from sheet 2 to the corresponding company in sheet 1? Or just copy all rows in sheet 2 that match the company names from sheet 1?

Comment: [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)??

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).